# How to chain an Observable if it depends upon the previous Observable?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm making a basic chat app. I have 3 basic classes. The `User` class stores the userName. The `Message` class stores the userId of the sender and the content. The `Chat` class contains a list of `Message`s. These classes also contain other data but that's not related to this question.

I can retrieve users by their ids. The `User`s are returned in the form of `Single<User>`.

To display a message in my UI, I need 2 things: the name of the sender and the content of the message. I put these into a helper class(`SimplifiedMessage`). I need to obtain a list of `SimplifiedMessage`s.

I already have the `Chat` object.

Basically, I need to get the list of all the messages and then for each message, get the name of the sender and then put the name and content together into a `SimplifiedMessage`. Finally, I have to collect all the `SimplifiedMessage`s together into a list. Also, this has to be done in order. If the chat holds the messages [M1, M2, M3], the list of `SimplifiedMessage`s should also be in the same order. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I know that the title of the question is really pathetic. Can anybody suggest a better title?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: @akarnokd thank you very much! It was just what I needed. I'll add the answer. Can you please suggest a better title for the question so that others may be able to find this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [RxJava Continuations](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations) as suggested by Akarnokd for explanation. My use case resembles the second snippet in the dependent continuations section. This code snippet will do the work:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(chat.messages)
    .concatMap { message ->
        repository.getUserById(message.senderId)
            .concatMap { user ->
                Flowable.just(SimpifiedMessage(user.name, message.content))
            }
    }
    .toList()
```

For those who are not familiar with concatMap, it is a flatMap that doesn't allow interleaving of emissions. This allows us to satisfy the order condition.